# Como extraer el IMEI numerico tal cual se muestra en el telefono al hacer *#06# desde mi aplicacion

Tags: android

Tengo el método bien implementado para extraer el imei en mi aplicación. El asunto es que me muestra el imei:52b3f8b114ff321f y lo que necesito es el formato numérico como el 35232143423546.

Comment: Que método usas para obtenerlo? Usas la clase TelephonyManager?

Comment: String myIMEI = Settings.Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

Comment: @ZanaxLobartis te sugiero revises [ask] por favor y también revises en el sitio, [información de esto ya se encuentra en el sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ANDROID+IMEI), saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba usando el metodo **getDeviceId()** de la clase **TelephonyManager**, que te devuelve un String con  el IMEI para la red GSM.
No olvides declarar en el Manifiest el permiso para poder leer la información de teléfono.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Te dejo un enlace a [la documentacion de android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getImei) para saber sobre la clase TelephonyManager.

Un ejemplo para implementarlo fuera del hilo principal:

```
public String obtenerIMEI(Context context){
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return tm.getImei();
}
```

Esta funcion te devuelve un String con el IMEI y se llamaria asi:

```
obtenerIMEI(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);....mi problema es que me da error el getSystemService... como que no reconoce este metodo

Comment: Estas usandolo fuera del hilo principal? Prueba a pasarle un Context desde el hilo principal y entonces haces un context.getSystemService...

Comment: Gracias, soy medico y estoy empezando con android... Todo ok ahora.